# Telerik MapPinPoint position cannot be set correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I´m using the Telerik RadMap and the VisualisationLayer to display the shapes of postal codes on a map.

```
<telerik:VisualizationLayer ItemsSource="{Binding MapItemCollection}" x:Name="VisualizationLayer">
    <telerik:VisualizationLayer.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <telerik:MapPolygonView telerik:MapLayer.Location="{Binding MapItemLocation}" Points="{Binding MapItemPoints}" local:MapUtility.ShapeColor="{Binding MapItemColor}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:VisualizationLayer.ItemTemplate>
</telerik:VisualizationLayer>
```

Until this point, everything works out fine, but when I´m trying to give this shape a Telerik.MapPinPoint as a title in the center of this shape. 
The position of the PinPoint gets overwritten by the position of the postal code shapes so that they are positioned on the edge of the shape instead of the center.

[image: Telerik Map Sample]

```
<telerik:VisualizationLayer ItemsSource="{Binding MapItemCollection}" x:Name="VisualizationLayer">
    <telerik:VisualizationLayer.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <telerik:MapPolygonView telerik:MapLayer.Location="{Binding MapItemLocation}" Points="{Binding MapItemPoints}" local:MapUtility.ShapeColor="{Binding MapItemColor}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:VisualizationLayer.ItemTemplate>
</telerik:VisualizationLayer>

<telerik:VisualizationLayer ItemsSource="{Binding MapItemCollection}" x:Name="Layer">
    <telerik:VisualizationLayer.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <telerik:MapPinPoint telerik:MapLayer.Location="{Binding PinPointLocation}"
                Background="#80808080"
                Foreground="White"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                BorderThickness="1"
                Text="{Binding PinPointText}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:VisualizationLayer.ItemTemplate>
</telerik:VisualizationLayer>
```

My Fix right now is to get another instance of the MapItem class for the PinPoint and set the MapItemLocation of this instance to Location.Empty. When I do this it also works out fine, but I would like to have all information considering one shape and the postcode together in one instance.

Answer (score 1):

So I got an answer of the Telerik Support, which I also asked for a solution of my problem.

Their Solution is to set the UseDefaultPropertyAccessor to false.

```
<telerik:VisualizationLayer ItemsSource="{Binding MapItemCollection}" x:Name="Layer" UseDefaultPropertyAccessor="False">
<telerik:VisualizationLayer.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <telerik:MapPinPoint telerik:MapLayer.Location="{Binding PinPointLocation}"
                Background="#80808080"
                Foreground="White"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                BorderThickness="1"
                Text="{Binding PinPointText}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</telerik:VisualizationLayer.ItemTemplate>
```

This fixes the problem and it now works as expected.
[image]